# hybris generates unnecessary and broken java files

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm in a new project and no one in our project know why this happens:

After I run `ant clean all`, it generates two java files:

- PunchOutCartBeforeViewHandlerTest
- SmarteditaddonCMSPageBeforeViewHandlerTest

Both are in our custom project folder.

Is there a way to figure out where that happens and also prevent them from getting generated?

---

The first error is this one:

```
1. ERROR in hybris/bin/custom/myproject/myprojectstorefront/web/addontestsrc/b2bpunchoutaddon/de/hybris/platform/b2bpunchoutaddon/interceptors/PunchOutCartBeforeViewHandlerTest.java (at line 43)
    private PunchOutBeforeViewHandler viewHandler;
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PunchOutBeforeViewHandler cannot be resolved to a type
```

First, it is the wrong class for the test and second it is the wrong package. The only possible class would be this one: `de.company.myproject.addon.b2bpunchoutaddon.interceptors.MyprojectPunchOutBeforeViewHandler`

Comment: How was MyprojectPunchOutBeforeViewHandler created? Did you create a custom addon?

Comment: It's extending b2bpunchoutaddon, I guess it's a custom addon, but I don't know how it was created. The project is a pretty old one and no one of the older team mates are in the project anymore.